# Creating a hooks-based setState that has a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I made the following example, when a setState occurs using the hooks, the possibility of being able to receive a callback is given when the operation was successful returning the changed state.

Kind of like it did:

```
this.setState({a: 1}, () => { 
   console.log("Ok.");
});
```

I wanted to know your opinion about it what do you think?

Could there be problems?

Can it be improved?

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-brown-pss9d)

App:

```
import React from "react";
import { useStateCallback } from "./useStateCallback";

export default function App() {
  const [stateString, setStateString] = useStateCallback("James");
  const [stateObj, setStateObj] = useStateCallback({
    name: "James",
    surname: "Bond",
    number: 7
  });

  const { name, surname, number } = stateObj;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setStateString("Bond");
    setStateString("Arthur", res => {
      console.log("State:", res);
    });
    setStateObj({
      ...stateObj,
      number: 1
    });
    setStateObj(
      {
        ...stateObj,
        name: "Arthur",
        surname: "Conan",
        number: 21
      },
      res => {
        console.log("State:", res);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      State: {stateString}
      <br />
      <br />
      Name: {name}
      <br />
      Surname: {surname}
      <br />
      Number: {number}
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```

useStateCallback:

```
import { useState } from "react";
const useStateCallback = initialState => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  return [
    state,
    (state, callback) => {
      setState(state);
      return callback && callback(state);
    }
  ];
};
export { useStateCallback };
```

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve with this? The callback in `this.setState()` executes when the state is actually updated and the component is re-rendered, but yours immediately executes the callback after calling `setState()`. So yours is just a convoluted way of executing one statement and then another. Seems a bit pointless and I think it might not actually do what you're intending for it to do.

Comment: It seems you've read my comment, so might you comment on what you're actually trying to do? Like an actual use case rather than the example you've provided? It may be that what you're trying to do can be achieved with `useEffect` but there's no way to know that unless you give us an actual example.

Comment: @JLRishe: Actually I had tagged you below, what I want to do is this.
Set the value of the element, it receives a callback that returns the complete state of the element just set, when the state has been set and has been updated so the rendering has taken place.
What this.setState ({}) does a little bit, something different I would like the state of the element to return to me and I would like to keep the calback structure just like setState () does.
`setStateObj (
{... stateObj, number: 21},
res => {console.log ("State:", res);} // Callback
);`

Comment: Ok, but can you describe an actual use case? As I've already said, your example above isn't very illustrative in showing how something like this would be useful, and I'm not sure why you have almost the entire thing wrapped in a `useEffect`

Comment: Think it has values that need to be set,
they can be set with a fetch or with input fields,
then only after the values have been set must a fetch be made to retrieve other information and set other values.
so there is a setstate and then a fetch call

Comment: Why is there a need to wait until the values are fully committed to the state before you initiate the fetch?

Comment: I'll give you an example I have a table with users near fetch.
I have a loadData () function, which takes care of this.
In this table I have the option to delete a user, a dialog window opens asking me for confirmation, when I confirm the Dialog Send function is called, which takes care of making a fetch, when the call is successful, it is closed the dialog, a props is executed that had been passed to the component located in the Father component, this props takes care of closing the dialog window and calling loadData ().

Comment: The problem is that if I call this function which is so made,
f () {CloseDialog ();
loadData ();}

They are done together and they give me problems.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see with this implementation:

1. You need to check if `callback` is a function or you opening a room for a runtime error:

```
setStateString('Arthur', { hello: 'hello' });
```

2. On every render, the custom hook returns a new instance of the setter function, which is not an expected behavior that can lead to rerunning `useEffect`s:

```
export default function App() {
  const [stateString, setStateString] = useStateCallback('James');
  const [, setCounter] = useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setStateString('Arthur', res => {
      console.log('State:', res);
    });
  }, [setStateString]);

  return (
    <div>
      State: {stateString}
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(p => p + 1)}>Render</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

To fix those issues, check the type of `callback` and memoize the setter:

```
export const useStateCallback = initialState => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const setter = useCallback((state, callback) => {
    setState(state);
    return typeof callback === 'function' && callback(state);
  }, []);
  return [state, setter];
};
```

[image: Edit Q-60226754-useStateCallbackFix]

> Side note, you may notice that this hook is exactly what `useEffect` does.

Comment: Could you better explain point 2.
You are right thinking well, it seems the same behavior as useEffect.
So maybe it's useless, and it doesn't exactly mean that I wanted, maybe @JLRishe is right.

Comment: You have codesandbox attached in the answer, try pressing the button with your implentation

Comment: He does right that its useless but it still a question

Comment: Forgive me I don't quite understand, how can I imitate the same behavior as this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-kj7oc

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-curran-pbldu, please don't ask new non-related questions in comments, post new questions on stack overflow.